# Animating Border Drop Shadow Effect

Tags: c#, wpf

I am trying to animate a drop shadow inside a generic theme for a user control

Given

```
<Border x:Name="PART_ClearBorder"
    <Border.Effect>
        <DropShadowEffect ShadowDepth="2" />
    </Border.Effect>
```

inside

```
<ControlTemplate.Triggers>
```

I have

```
<MultiTrigger>
    <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
        <Condition SourceName="PART_Clear" Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True" />
        <Condition Property="HasText" Value="True" />
    </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
    <Setter TargetName="PART_Clear" Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource ClearHighlightBrush}" />
    <MultiTrigger.EnterActions>
        <BeginStoryboard>
            <Storyboard>
                <DoubleAnimation AutoReverse="True"
                                    Duration="0:0:0.5"
                                    From="0"
                                    Storyboard.TargetName="{Binding ElementName=PART_ClearBorder}"
                                    Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Effect).(DropShadowEffect.ShadowDepth)"
                                    To="30" />
            </Storyboard>
        </BeginStoryboard>
    </MultiTrigger.EnterActions>
</MultiTrigger>
```

Note The important part is the double animation trying to target the ShadowDepth property

Which is throwing a `System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException` when i run the project

im also getting an underline in the xaml main form

> Error 2   Cannot freeze this Storyboard timeline tree for use across
>   threads.

What is the correct way to maybe *boiler plate* the story board correctly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
<Border x:Name="PART_ClearBorder" >
    <Border.Effect>
        <DropShadowEffect x:Name="dropEffect" ShadowDepth="2" />
    </Border.Effect>
```

And your storyboard

```
<DoubleAnimation AutoReverse="True"
                 Duration="0:0:0.5"
                 From="0"
                 Storyboard.TargetName="dropEffect"
                 Storyboard.TargetProperty="ShadowDepth"
                 To="30" />
```

Comment: in visual studio 2019 this does not work.
>> InvalidOperationException: A Storyboard tree in a Style cannot specify a TargetName. Remove TargetName 'ZetaGlow'.